# How to set a stub for all tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec2

In controller I'm using external geocoding service with line:

```
loc = Location.geocode(@event.raw_location)
```

I'd like to set a stub for all my tests with:

```
allow(Location).to receive(:geocode).with(nil).and_return({city: nil, state: nil, country: nil})
```

Where should I put this code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should declare a global `before(:each)` in your `rails_helper.rb` or `spec_helper.rb`

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:each) do
    allow(Location).to receive(:geocode).with(nil).and_return({city: nil, state: nil, country: nil})
  end
end
```

EDIT:

Also, if you want to run this 'global' `before(:each)` only for the tests that involving the geocoding calls, you can write:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:each, geocoding_mock: true) do
    allow(Location).to receive(:geocode).with(nil).and_return({city: nil, state: nil, country: nil})
  end
end
```

then in your tests:

```
describe Location, geocoding_mock: true do
...
end
```